# unable to use ajax to call webserver to get return result in .net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have tried to use the following code to retrieve the data from the webserver (test.asmx.cs) but somehow this is always throw the error to me... does anyone know what is it going wrong?

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for autocomplete
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class autocomplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string streetNameSearch(int id)
        {

            return "Melbourne|North Melbourne|South Melbourne|Richmond|North Richmond";
        }
    }
}
```

And the following jquery code have placed under pgTest.aspx

```
$("#example").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pgTest.aspx/streetNameSearch",
        data: '{"id":"' + 1 + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var returnData = data.d;
            alert(returnData)

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(ajaxOptions);
    },
    timeout: function (data) {
        alert("time out");
    }
});
});
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: @jon3laze: the error is just 'error',

Comment: put a breakpoint in your method streetNameSearch and check whether it is called?

Comment: @jayantha, this is gone through to the error part and not even manage to call to the method streetNameSearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment this line:

```
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

The ScriptService attribute enables all of an ASMX service’s methods to respond with raw JSON.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to uncommenting the `ScriptService` line, why is your `$.ajax()` method targeting an ASPX path while the code you posted is from an ASMX service?  That could definitely cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     public static JsonResult streetNameSearch(string id)
        {

            return Json("Melbourne|North Melbourne|South Melbourne|Richmond|North Richmond");
        }
```

And in your javascript change like this

```
data: {id:"1"}
```

Comment: @Jayanthan: seem like JsonResult and Json() is not support in .net c# webservice